# tahoe-lafs: one full copy of every file per server

Tags: networking, storage, redundancy

I am attempting to use Tahoe-LAFS to make data available on all the machines I have set a share up on. At the moment, there are two machines acting as storage nodes. I will soon be adding a third.

How can I have one full copy of a file per server? I require this since two of the computers on the network are laptops, and I need to retain access even when they are offline.

Failing this, are there any distributed file systems that would fit that use case well? Note that supporting OS X boxes for storage is a requirement.